# File Upload to HTTP server from iPhone application. Server side C# API method

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Could someone please tell me/link me to how I could create a method similar to those posted below:
http://www.vimeo.com/api/docs/upload
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html
(I am providing the links as I'm not sure how to articulate this question without them!)

I'm using C# ASP.NET. IIS 6.
I have an existing web server with other public API methods. I do not want the iPhone user to have to open a web browser, and post to an aspx page. I want the iPhone developer to be able to call my method, and have one of the parameters be a handle to the file which gets POSTed.   
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a WCF Service Application. You can use this as a webservice that can be exposed to your clients. You can create a RESTful service using WCF where clients can POST video's to.

When searching for 'REST, API, WCF' you'll probably find all the resources you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I currently have this service setup. It produces myService.svc on my server. My clients can access it. However, I need to be able to create a method which receives a file. None of the resources I've found explain how to do this. They all send & receive Strings/Bools/ints &c. or composite objects made up of those.

Comment: For a video, use a `byte[]`, your clients can POST base64 encoded video to it.